# SoundCloud Custom Player Install

Tags: jquery, html, css, soundcloud

I read the "Quick Start" guide found here
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/wiki#wiki-quick-start and after following the instructions i placed the HTML code to produce the custom player like so  `<a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic" class="sc-player-minimal">My new dub track</a>` but the output is only a text link. View here http://soundcloudtest.virb.com/soundcloud

I've placed the player css file into the "head" section of the themes layout here:

[image]

And then placed the script tags within the 'body' section of the themes layout here:

[image]

What could i be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing https and http scripts and resources. Try changing https to http and report what happens.

Comment: @vidario, okay, thought so. I'll fix this and report back.

Comment: Are you already using jQuery? Might be that it's being loaded twice. Also the guide says at the end of the body tag, you've got the calls at the start there.

Comment: @vidario i've updated it all back to http but no changes to the problem. :(

Comment: @AlexLynham from what i could tell, i did not seen any other jQuery being used. I've also moved the script tags to the bottom of the body tag as suggested but still no change. :(

Comment: okay, on your page I'm getting two uncaught TypeErrors - both related to the isotope script. You may want to inspect that yourself... but that's possibly why the scripts aren't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the player error by changing both the css link inside the 'head' section and html code from `sc-player-minimal.css` to `sc-player.css`

Answer (score 0):

Your example link seems to work now.

Comment: Hello @gryzzly 

While the player is working correctly on comp. browsers, i did notice it will not play on my Android device. Any ideas on how to fix this?